# Specify the inequality Constraint in Scipy optimization

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I was trying to build an optimization problem to determine the weights for the assets in my portfolio. I am a bit confused oh how I should mention the inequality constraint

I am trying to minimize the sharpe ratio on two constraints:
1. that summation of weights must be equal to one (Equality Constraint)
2. that a weight value cant exceed 1

```
import scipy.optimize as spo

def sharpe(dr, riskf, wts):
    portfolio=np.ones(dr.shape[0])
    dr[0:]=wts*dr[0:]
    portfolio[0:]=dr.sum(axis=1)

    net=portfolio.copy()
    net[0:]=portfolio[0:]-riskf[0:]
    sharpe_ratio=-np.mean(net)/np.std(net) 
    return sharpe_ratio

def wts_con(wts):
    return wts[0]+wts[1]+wts[2]+wts[3]-1

def range_con():


def sharpe_optimize(dr, riskf, sharpe):
    wts_guess=np.array([0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25])

    con=[{"type"="eq", "fun"=wts_con}
         {"type"="ineq", "fun"=range_con}]

    result=spo.minimize(sharpe, wts_guess, args={dr,riskf,}, method="SLSQP", constraints=con, options={"disp":True})
    return result
```

I wanted to know how I can write range_con() function which specifies that my individual weights cant go below 0 or above 1

Comment: `scipy.optimize.minimize` accepts a `bounds` argument, which is a list of tuples specifying the permissible range of each of the optimization variables. See the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) (in particular, the second example)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I could also use your help with the question in the following
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39310546/getting-an-error-could-not-broadcast-input-array-from-shape-252-4-into-shape)