# Getting an error "could not broadcast input array from shape (252,4) into shape (4)" in optimization

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I a relatively new to python scipy library. I was trying to use the scipy.optimize to find the maximum value of the sharpe() function in the following code

```
def sharpe(dr, wts):
    portfolio=np.ones(dr.shape[0])
    dr[0:]=wts*dr[0:]
    sharpe_ratio=-np.mean(np.sum(dr, axis=1))/np.std(np.sum(dr, axis=1))
    return sharpe_ratio

def wts_con(wts):
    return wts[0]+wts[1]+wts[2]+wts[3]-1

def sharpe_optimize(dr, sharpe_func):
    wts_guess=np.array([0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25])

    con=[{"type":"eq", "fun":wts_con}]
    bnds=((0,1),(0,1),(0,1),(0,1))

    result=spo.minimize(sharpe_func, wts_guess, args=(dr,), method="SLSQP", constraints=con, bounds=bnds, options={"disp":True})
   return result
```

In the above code dr is a size(252,4) array and wts is a size(4) array

I am getting the following error in line 3 when I call the sharpe_optimize() function

> could not broadcast input array from shape (252,4) into shape (4)

Comment: You need to give more of the error stack.  And maybe a runnable case with a smaller `dr` array.  The error is probably the result of trying to assign the `dr` values to a `wts` shaped array, e.g. `wts[:] = dr`.  But I don't know where that is happening.

Comment: Try switching the `wts` and `dr` arguments in `sharpe`.  The first is the one that `minimize` steps, that matches `wts_guess` (4,).  The second argument is the one passed from `args`, that is just a way of passing extra information to your function.

Comment: @hpaulj that worked. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to swap the arguments in your definition of the `sharpe` function. It is defined as `sharpe(dr,wts)` but then it looks like you call minimize as `sharpe(wts,dr)` based on your use of `args`. Edit: I have just seen that this is pointed out in the above comments!

Comment: Yup, the solution did work, Thanks anyways for the help